# Commands not working on xterm but work in ssh session

Tags: bash, ssh, xfce, ruby, xrdp

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 with Xrdp and Xfce4 for remote access. Installed ruby using RVM. When I try to access Ruby Interactive (irb), it works perfectly from the SSH shell (I type irb and I can use the interactive ruby environment). However when I do remote logon and use Xterm, it cannot find a lot of commands (like `irb`, `reboot`, `shutdown`)
I query using RVM again and see ruby is installed. This is not only about ruby, I see many other commands are not accessible.

When I type

```
echo $SHELL
```

I see

```
/bin/bash
```

Comment: How can you log in remotely via Xterm? That's a terminal emulator with no knowledge of remote sessions or networking whatsoever. Of course you can run remote sessions in a virtual terminal but that's another story. Could you please [edit] your question to clarify what you're actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

`bash` searches for the command you type (assuming the command is NOT an alias or a builtin and doesn't start with "`/`") in the directories listed in the colon-separated list contained in the `PATH` variable. `echo $PATH` to show it. I don't have `irb` installed, but `reboot` and `shutdown` are in the `/sbin/` directory.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

will make `reboot` and `shutdown` visible.

You can find where `irb` is located by logging in with `ssh`, then

```
type -p irb
```

Add this directory to your `PATH`.

Check your terminal type (`echo $TERM`) in each environment, and see if `$TERM` affects your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PATH variable is differently constructed depending on how to enter the shell.

You could double check with

```
echo $PATH
```

for the differences.

I've no experience with Ruby's environment but I could imagine there's a script being sourced which sets up everything (e.g. like with node/npm).

Bash is potentially sourcing multiple scripts like /etc/profile, ~/.profile ~/.bash_rc, /etc/bash.bashrc.

Perhaps your xterm configuration makes use of --noprofile or --norc or it's not invoked as login shell and therefore is not sourcing a relevant part for setting up your Ruby environment.

From man bash:

```
When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a  non-
inter-active  shell with the --login option, it first reads and 
executes com-mands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. 
After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, 
and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from 
the first one that exists  and  is  readable.  The --noprofile option 
may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
```

and

```
When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash 
reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc  and  ~/.bashrc, if
these files exist. This may be inhibited by using the --norc option.
```

Edit: here's a screenshot showing what needs to be configured for xterm

[image]

Original source here: https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal